# 'GET-EVENTLOG' creating a full object list, then being filtered ? - is there quicker way?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, get-eventlog

The following Powershell script fetches all the System Error Events occuring today only - it works:

```
Get-EventLog System -After ([datetime]::Today) | Where-Object { $_.EntryType -eq "Error" }
```

But it can take several seconds to run : I suspect this is because the first'Get-EventLog' cmdlet is generating the complete list of *all* events first; then the 'Where-Object' cmdlet trims down that list.

Is a way of passing in the 'where-object' filter as an argument to the 'Get-EventLog' so that it could test each object as it fetches them ?

I am speculating that such a mechanism would be quicker to run, since the 'Get-EventLog' wouldn't have to maintain the full list of objects that are passed to the subsequent 'Where-Object' ?

But I'm just guessing here.

Also: this isn't such a big deal - it's just a point of interest/understanding on my part.

Answer (score 3):

```
Get-EventLog System -After ([datetime]::Today) -EntryType Error
```

Yes, you can specify this parameter in the original command.

Comment: Oops: I have missed that in the help - yes - this works much faster.

Comment: (But I guess in *general* you can't just 'pass-in' a filter to arbitary cmdlets, rather you have to join them at the end of the Object-Pipeline (which does seem to have performance implications - especially with a 'select-object First 1' for instance)

Comment: actually - I'm not sure it is faster  (maybe it has more to do with that fact that the EventLog is a dynamically changing thing, which needs to be locked etc by the system) : but is more convenient and easier to read in any case.

Comment: Mostly depends how the function was designed, here it is build into the command :
SYNTAX
    Get-EventLog [-LogName] <String> [[-InstanceId] [<Int64[]>]] [-After [<DateTime>]] [-AsBaseObject] [-Before [<DateTime>]] [-ComputerName 
    [<String[]>]] **[-EntryType {Error | Information | FailureAudit | SuccessAudit | Warning}]** [-Index [<Int32[]>]]...

Comment: Filtering depends mostly of what I parse and what I need. If I'm going to work with large amount of objects (ie: all AD computers or users) or smaller one (an array of 20 servers). First solution, I'll try to narrow down my initial search as much as possible, second one, I'll try to keep as much properties as possible to not be limited by my object.